# Email not to use my details as on behalf

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I have created shared mailbox for our team: `TeamMail@inbox.com`.

Currently I am trying to use it in one of my flows. Flow gets triggered when new item is added to list, there is a condition that if Status of created item is Open, it send an email.

Email is sent on behalf of Team Mail.

Question: How do I get it to stop using my name as on behalf and just send an email using shared mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest you use "send an email from a shared mailbox" action.
>
> And to let it work, we need give 'Send on behalf' permission to 'the connection account that run this action' from admin.microsoft.com as [Create a shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-a-shared-mailbox)

[image]

**Reference**: [Sending emails as a shared mailbox](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sending-emails-as-a-shared-mailbox/td-p/713366)

Also, If you are creating a new flow then you can start with using below flow template which has same use case as yours:

[Send an email from a shared mailbox when an item is created in SharePoint](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/5271d15c6fc240c99e88ecb8e4e43d4e/send-an-email-from-a-shared-mailbox-when-an-item-is-created-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I have tried this option too and it is still sending emails on behalf of Team and not from the Team.